# Issue with declaring inputs to geometry shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I am trying to pass vertex attributes from my vertex shader -> geometry shader and then to the fragment shader.

Pretty simple program, here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 440 core

uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjMatrix;

in vec4 aPosition;

out vec3 modelPosition;

void main()
{
    modelPosition = aPosition.xyz;
    gl_Position = uProjMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aPosition;
}
```

Here is my geometry shader:

```
#version 440 core

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

in vec3 modelPosition[];

out vec3 gModelPosition[];

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
    {
        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        EmitVertex();
    }
    gModelPosition[0] = modelPosition[0];
    gModelPosition[1] = modelPosition[1];
    gModelPosition[2] = modelPosition[2];
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

And here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 440 core

in vec3 gModelPosition;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(gModelPosition, 1.0);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR: error: "gModelPosition" not declared as input from previous stage
```

If I just comment out the last line in the fragment shader, and say `fragColor = vec4(1.0);` it works fine. And I clearly **am** declaring gModelPosition as an input from the previous stage.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, you can answer your own question. Deleting it just means the next person with a similar problem won't get the benefit of your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I declared `out vec3 gModelPosition[]` as an array in my geometry shader.

It should have only been declared as a `vec3` (i.e. `out vec3 gModelPosition`)

Comment: You should also write to them the same way you write to `gl_Position`: before calling `EmitVertex()`.